# Should I make and implement a network protocol by hand or use a middleware (if so which)?

Tags: network-programming

I have some data that I need to share between multiple services on multiple machines.  Stuffing the data into a database or shuffling it over http won't work in this situation and ideally the different pieces of software will need to communicate with each other directly (or through one central coordinator that can send and receive).

Is it recommended to create and implement a network protocol or use some tool to do the communication?

If I did go the route of creating a protocol myself, it wouldn't have to be very complex.  Under 10 different message types, but it would have to be re-implemented in a few different languages for this project, and support unicode. I have read plenty (and done some) with handling sockets, but don't have much knowledge in handling a protocol I create.  Are there any good resources on this?

There are also things like ICE and RPC that look intresting.  The limit of my experience is using ICE and XMLRPC for a few days each.  Is this the better route to go? If so what tools are out there?

Comment: out of curiosity, could you expand on why an existing protocol wouldn't do the trick? are you implementing peer-to-peer style agents? what sort of environment(s) is your system needing to exist in?

Comment: An existing protocol isn't out of the question, I'm willing to use another protocol to shuffle the data around (and why I mention building on top of other tools).  I haven't thought of using a particular existing protocol because don't know of any particular protocol that would do the trick.  The only existing one I can think of to use would be http, and the reason I don't want to use that is because I don't want to be constantly polling.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been using [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) for encoding and shipping data between different machines running software written in different languages. It is quite easy to do, and takes away a lot of the hassle of designing a custom protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what technologies and platforms you are dealing with, it's difficult to give you a very specific answer - so I'll try to give you some general feedback.

If the system(s) you are wishing to connect span more than a single platform and/or technology you are probably better using an existing transport mechanism and protocol to maximize the chance your base platform will already have a library (or multiple) to interact over it. Also, integrating security and other features in a stack with known behaviors is more likely to be documented (with examples floating around). RPC (and ICE, though I've less familiarity with it) has some useful capabilities, but it also requires a lot of control over the environment and security can be convoluted (particularly if you are passing objects between different languages).

With regards to avoiding polling, this is a performance related issue; there are design patterns which can help you to handle such things - if you understand how you need the system to work (e.g. the observer pattern - kind of a dont-call-us-we'll-call-you approach). The network environment you are playing in will dictate which options are actually viable (e.g. a local LAN will have different considerations from something which runs over a WAN or the internet). Factors like firewall tunneling, VPN traversal, etc. should play part in your final selected technology profile.

The only other major consideration (that I can think of just now... ;-)) would be to consider the type of data you need to pass about. Is it just text, or do you need to stream binary objects? Would an encoding format (like XML or JSON or bJSON) do the trick? You mention "less than ten message types" as part of the question, but is that the only information which would ever need to be communicated by the system?

Either way, unless the overhead of existing protocols is unacceptable you're better of leveraging established work 99% of the time. Creativity is great - but commercial projects usually benefit from well-known behaviors, even if not the coolest or slickest (kind of the "as long as it works..." approach).

hth!